# purpose of stack segment in assembly language

Tags: stacks, assembly

The code snippet below is the "beginning lines of an assembly language program" used to display a single line string .

```
stack segment para stack 'stack'
       db 16 dup(0)
stack ends
```

my question is : why stack segment is available in assembly program? And how do I define this 'stack'? Any help will be appreciated. My basic idea is that it is used to temporarily hold data.

Comment: There are several relevant articles on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation